# Counting 1s in the two's complement representations of integers in range[x,y]

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary

My question is related to a previous question in the forum -
[Number of 1s in the two's complement binary representations of integers in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942732/number-of-1s-in-the-twos-complement-binary-representations-of-integers-in-a-ran)
There was no 'add comment' for me.So i am asking it here
The question was to count the number of 1's in writing down all numbers in 2's complement form,which are in a range specified by two input numbers
The solution is posted at https://gist.github.com/1285119
 It is as below

```
long long solve(int a)
  {
  if(a == 0) return 0 ;
  if(a % 2 == 0) return solve(a - 1) + __builtin_popcount(a) ;
  return ((long long)a + 1) / 2 + 2 * solve(a / 2) ;
  }


 long long solve(int a,int b)
 {
  if(a >= 0)
  {
   long long ret = solve(b) ;
   if(a > 0) ret -= solve(a - 1) ;
   return ret ;
   }
 long long ret = (32LL * -(long long)a) - solve(~a) ;
 if(b > 0) ret += solve(b) ;
 else if(b < -1)
 {
  b++ ;
  ret -= (32LL * -(long long)b) - solve(~b) ;
 }
return ret ;
}
```

When the input is
4  //No of test cases

-1   //first number
-2   //Second number
Output 0

-1
-3
 Output -31

-3
-5
Output -30   //how can number of 1's be -30

1
2
Output 2

Since the code is posted as Codesprint solutions on InterviewStreet and a highly voted answer on this forum.It should have been correct.
Can anyone explain the logic behind the line 
long long ret = (32LL * -(long long)a) - solve(~a)  in solve(int a,int b)
And what is the purpose of #define INF (int)1e9 //setting value of infinity when not using it?

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660937/1011995) for example.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong results for your inputs

```
-1 -2
-1 -3
-3 -5
```

are because the programme assumes that the two limits are entered in ascending order and does no checks, therefore input not conforming to that expectation produces wrong results. A simple

```
if (b < a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

at the beginning of `int solve(int a, int b)` would make it return the correct result for input in any order.

The logic behind `long long ret = (32LL * -(long long)a) - solve(~a)` is that (in twos' complement) the bitwise complement of `n` is `~n = (-n)-1`. The total number of bits (0 or 1) in the numbers from `a` to `-1` - both inclusive - is `32 * |a|` if `a < 0`. From that count, we subtract the total number of 0 bits in these numbers, which is the total number of 1-bits in their bitwise complements. These bitwise complements are the numbers from 0 to `|a| - 1 = ~a`, both inclusive, the count of 1-bits among these is given by `solve(|a| - 1) = solve(~a)`.